# Driver and car class: where would I write drive() method?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Here's a model in reference to my question:
[O-O model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvXWm.png)

When implementing the code, I imagine myself writing a class for "Driver", and another for "Car". If I were to write a method (drive car, operate wipers, apply breaks, etc), is it recommended that I write them in the Driver class file or Car file?

Comment: Both, probably. The `driver` owns a `car`, and part of `driver.operateWipers()` involves calling `car.operateWipers()`.

Comment: I Agree with @GreenCloakGuy, both driver and car will end up with different abstractions from same methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram shows where the methods should go.  Which is in the Car class.

BUT, I would slightly change your method calls:

- break()
- releaseBreak()
- turnOnWipers()
- turnOffWipers()

But overall it would be the driver that calls those methods on the car.

BTW, it doesn't HAVE to be a Driver driving the Car, just something that knows about a Car's interface and how to interact with it.  Think self driving cars, etc...